# How to use inline-c to wrap functions returning pointer to custom struct type?

Tags: haskell

I plan to use `inline-c` to wrap a C function:

```
lxw_workbook  *workbook  = workbook_new("filename.xlsx");
```

I need to capture the returned Ptr to use in other functions later.

Question:
The Ptr points to lxw_workbook which is a custom struct. Do I need to write a Storage instance for a Haskell type corresponding to this?
Because if I don't use the struct directly, only the Ptr, can I skip this step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type argument to `Ptr` is just a tag, to remind you what it's pointing to. The type doesn't need to be `Storable` or anything. Note that your situation is not novel; the C standard library contains types like `FILE` which are only accessed through pointers, just like yours. Following their lead, you can write a dummy type

```
data Workbook = Workbook -- constructor does not have to/should not be exported
```

and then you can write a `Context` containing that type:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Context as C
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Types as C

lxwContext :: C.Context
lxwContext = mempty { ctxTypesTable = M.singleton (C.TypeName "lxw_workbook") [t| Workbook |] }
```

Which can then be loaded as usual

```
import qualified Language.Inline.C as C

C.context (baseCtx <> lxwContext)

C.include "whatever.h" -- wherever you get workbook_new from

example :: IO (Ptr Workbook)
example = [C.exp| lxw_workbook* { workbook_new("filename.xlsx") } ]
```